# How can I write to a MySQL database in parallel? (same table, different records)

Tags: mariadb

I'm having trouble running multiple processes that write to a database at once (same table but different records). I'm able to run one process and have my program write to the database, but when I try to run multiples processes, I can't connect to the database from the other processes. In particular, I get:

```
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

I'm guessing this has to do with database locks, but I'm not experienced enough with this to know for sure.

Here is how I start the mysql server:

```
mysqld_safe --socket=mysql.sock --log-error=mysql.log --datadir=mysql_data --pid-file=mariadb.pid --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED &
```

I initially didn't have `--transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED`, but I added it because I thought it might help, but it didn't.

I was wondering if I can get some guidance on how to make this work.

EDIT: My application is basically a Python script that uses Optuna, a machine learning hyperparameter optimization framework.
The relevant code is:

```
storage_name = "mysql+pymysql://mdanb:password@localhost:3306/optuna_db"

study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize",
                            storage=storage_name,
                            study_name=study_name,
                            load_if_exists=True,
sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=seed))
```

I'm basically running the script multiple times from different nodes, and running `mysqld_safe --socket=mysql.sock --log-error=mysql.log --datadir=mysql_data --pid-file=mariadb.pid --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED &` once before running any instance of the script. The first instance always works, but anything after that doesn't.

Comment: What about use of a stored procedure and put all the transactions between the START TRANSACTION;   and the last statement being COMMIT; so that they all get the data they need BEFORE making the changes.

Comment: WHat exactly do you mean by multiple processes?

Comment: Are you suggesting that yuo are trying to start more than one instance of mariaDB?

Comment: "No route to host" is a network problem, has nothing to do with the database query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm running multiple instances of the same script, which is basically a script that uses Optuna (machine learning hyperparameter optimization framework) to find the best hyperparameters for a model

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm only running `mysqld_safe --socket=mysql.sock --log-error=mysql.log --datadir=mysql_data --pid-file=mariadb.pid --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED &` once

Comment: @easleyfixed I'm not sure I totally understand. I'm going to clarify my application in an edit to the post

Comment: I think you are doing something different that I was talking about with procedures and transactions, you are running multiple copies of the same script and not needing to do multiple transactions at the same time, so my suggestion is probably not an option for this.

Comment: @easleyfixed correct

Comment: This is a theory but if all those scripts are doing statements that might be intensive, perhaps too much I/O is going on for it to handle the output speed and maybe some db config settings might help it depending on what's under the hood, but without some numbers its all speculation.

Comment: what operating system are you doing this on?  the manually starting mysqld_safe rather than as a normal service seems like the most likely place you could be going wrong.  and it's weird to be using relative paths for your pid file/socket/log.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, one possible solution is Using a connection pool to manage database connections. Instead of each process attempting to connect independently, this would enable numerous processes to share a pool of connections to the database.